# How to concatenate two variable of which one is string and other is not

Tags: python-2.7

I want my function to search for two indexes say "name" and "state". This is done and assigned to two separate variables. name is already a string and we want to convert the state to a string. I want to concatenate this two varibales. nearcity is a string and state is not. I want the state to be converted to string and concatenate both. How can it be done. Its simple i think but i am new to python

```
if valTest:
            idx = layer.fieldNameIndex('name')  #name of the attribute column with the cities in it
            idx1 = layer.fieldNameIndex('state')
            nearCity = f.attributes()[idx]
            state = f.attributes()[idx1]
```

Comment: Please **edit the question** to include your code and the full error traceback. `state&cities` is not a valid Python identifier, try `states_and_cities`.

Comment: I tried state_and_cities = nearCity +''+ str(state). The both the values are writted in one cell in a csv file. How do make it separate?

Comment: ...separate them with a comma?! You aren't showing any CSV handling, so it's pretty much impossible to guess that's what you're doing. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: State_and_Cities = nearCity + , +str(state). Its saying invalid syntax

Comment: You can't just have a random comma, of course that is not valid syntax. You need **a string** - `','` (or just use `','.join((nearCity, str(state))`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do:

```
s = near_city + "," + str(state)
```

Comment: Yeah both the values are writed within one cell in a csv file. How this should be solved?

Comment: Thank you all for your time and patience